# Mongoose object id is null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm creating an object Registration (a Mongoose Schema) and I need to set its `Id` in `User` with this line: `registrationId: registration._id});`

However, the `Id` is still `null`, even though it's the callback function? When I check the database the Registration has and Id of course, but not in the callback. How can I set the `Id` of the `Registration` in `User`?

Edit2: changed to minimal example. This prints out two times `null`.

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  Registration.create(req.body, function(err, registration) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }

    console.log(registration._id);
    console.log(registration.id);

    return res.json(201, registration);
  });
};
```

Edit: this is the schema (I left out some fields that are not required):

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var RegistrationSchema = new Schema({

    isReservation: Boolean,

    //Id of the trip
    tripId: String,

    //socialMutuality
    codeGerechtige: String,
    socialMutualityNumberParent1: String,
    socialMutualityNumberParent2: String,

    //contact
    userId: String,
    firstnameContact: String,
    lastnameContact: String,
    emailContact: String,
    streetContact: String,
    streetNumberContact: String,
    zipcodeContact: String,
    busContact: String,
    cityContact: String,
    phoneContact: String,
    gsmContact: String,
    socialSecurityNumberContact: String,

    //coordinats of person that pays

    //child information

    //emergency contacts
    emergencyContacts: [{
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        phone: String
    }],

    extraInfo: String

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Registration', RegistrationSchema);
```

**Problem and solution:** the problem was the client sending an attribute _id = null, and that's why MongoDB/Mongoose didn't update the id.

Comment: OK, I changed the first code part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something else going on in your code which is effecting this. This example works as expected for me:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/createid');

var RegistrationSchema = new Schema({

    isReservation: Boolean,

    //Id of the trip
    tripId: String,

    //socialMutuality
    codeGerechtige: String,
    socialMutualityNumberParent1: String,
    socialMutualityNumberParent2: String,

    //contact
    userId: String,
    firstnameContact: String,
    lastnameContact: String,
    emailContact: String,
    streetContact: String,
    streetNumberContact: String,
    zipcodeContact: String,
    busContact: String,
    cityContact: String,
    phoneContact: String,
    gsmContact: String,
    socialSecurityNumberContact: String,

    //coordinats of person that pays

    //child information

    //emergency contacts
    emergencyContacts: [{
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        phone: String
    }],

    extraInfo: String

});

var Registration = mongoose.model('Registration', RegistrationSchema);

var reg = {
    userId: '1234',
    tripId: '2345',
    firstnameContact: 'Timothy',
    lastnameContact: 'Strimple',
    emailContact: 'tim@tstrimple.com'
};

Registration.create(reg, function(err, registration) {
    if(err) { throw err; }
    console.log(registration._id);
});
```

I get a valid id written out to the console.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. registration._id stays null. I really don't know why the callback is executed before the id is generated.

Comment: Lets see your schema definition for Registration.

Comment: Ok, added to the first post. Thanks!

Comment: Something else must be going on. See my updated example which works for me.

Comment: You say the value inside the database does have a valid _id? I was wondering if _id is defined in req.body which was causing it to be null.

Comment: Indeed. I was just checking that. This looks to be the problem. I'll test it now to be sure. Stupid mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had the same problem having `_id` as null in`req.body`.

Comment: Is there a way to autogenerate the object id even if the _id is null in the req body?

Answer (score 6):

removing _id from req.body fixed my issue.

```
if(req.body._id === null) {
  delete req.body._id;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use undefined instead of null and it will generate an id for you. In my case changing what was a null to undefined on this line fixed it: `_id: newUser ? undefined : selectedUser._id`